# How do I set up AD FS 2.0 with a SAML 1.1 profile using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, adfs2.0, adfs

I’m working on a Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise server.  I am trying to script the creation of a relying party trust for our production servers.  I’ve written a powershell script.  When I create the relying party trust manually, I selelct SAML 1.1 profile and everything works.  When I create a script and use the powershell command `Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust`, it does not work the same and I get the following error:

> The Federation Service could  not authorize token issuance for caller 'xxxx\xxxxx
>   '. The caller is not authorized to request a token for the relying party 'https://example.com/forms/'. Please see event 501 with the same instance id for caller identity.

When I search on that error, it appears to me (though I could be wrong) that it’s a SAML 2.0 profile issue.  But I need SAML 1.1.

Here is the code where I create the relying party trust:

```
Write-Host "Configuring relying party trust."
Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -Identifier "$endpoint" -Name "$name" -WSFedEndpoint "$endpoint/" -SignatureAlgorithm "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"
Write-Host "Configuring rules."
$ruleSet = New-ADFSClaimRuleSet -ClaimRule 'c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"] => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname"), query = ";userPrincipalName,mail,givenName,sn;{0}", param = c.Value);'
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -TargetIdentifier "$endpoint" -IssuanceTransformRules $ruleSet.ClaimRulesString
Write-Host "Done."
```

When I do a `GetADFSRelyingPartyTrust` on the relying trust that works and compare it to the one the does not work, see a difference in the rule template:

#### Works:

> IssuanceAuthorizationRules           : @RuleTemplate = "AllowAllAuthzRule"
>                                           => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit", Val
>                                          ue = "true");

#### Doesn’t Work:

> IssuanceAuthorizationRules           :

Any ideas on how to get rid of the above error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By asking the question and providing the above information I found my own answer:

I needed to pass the -IssuanceAuthorizationRules parameter to the command.

> -IssuanceAuthorizationRules '@RuleTemplate = "AllowAllAuthzRule" => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit", Value = "true");'